# Cut n Paste Results into Excel - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I know how to export a file from workbench and upload into Excel for analysis. Recently I had a windows computer with workbench and I could just select all results from a query and then paste into a spreadsheet.
I recently moved to a Mac and downloaded the version 6.2 of MySQL Workbench. Now when I cut n paste to excel each row is within one field/column like so:

```
'814','BW Free report','4','0','0'
```

All of this is inside one cell and not broken out by columns like it used to automatically do.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered your own question, but for completeness (and to include additional options) from the results view you can do one of three options:

(**Option A**): *Copy-n-paste All or Some results*

1. Execute your statement
2. Select All (Control+A or Command+A) results, or select the results you desire
3. Right-click on the results view panel and choose "Copy row (tab separated)" -- this actually copies all selected rows (despite only saying "Copy row")
4. Paste into Excel

(**Option B**): *Data Export All Results*

1. Execute your statement
2. Click the Data Export icon under the results view (or choose "Export Results" 
   under the "Query" navigation menu
3. Choose "Excel Spreadsheet" or "Tab separated" as the Export File type, depending on your desire
4. Import the file into Excel

(**Option C**): *On Windows, instead use MySQL for Excel* -- An Excel plugin

1. For additional information, see http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/

Answer (score 0):

I found that by selecting the results and then pressing control+click I could copy as tab delimitated which appears to have solved the problem - the data now paste into the correct rows